# Object scoping using computed observables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am currently having difficulty scoping within an object using [`computed observables`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and hoping someone could assist me!

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/6s8WC/2/)***

Basically, I have an object (made simple to illustrate the issue):

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable('John'),
    lastName: ko.observable('Doe'),
    fullName: ko.computed(function(){
        return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
    }, this)
};
```

I want to reference that current objects properties, so I do the following:

```
fullName: ko.computed(function(){
    return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
 }, this);
      ^------- thought 'this' would refer to 'viewModel'
```

Now, I thought `this` would refer to my object, `viewModel`, but instead it is referring to the `window`.

As a result, an error is thrown saying `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"` since `window` does not have the methods `firstName()` or `lastName()`.

*HTML:*

```
<div>
    <strong>First Name:</strong>
    <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>

    <strong>Last Name:</strong>
    <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>

    <strong>Full Name:</strong>
    <span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
</div>
```

*JS:*

```
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable('John'),
    lastName: ko.observable('Doe'),
    fullName: ko.computed(function(){
        // this = window
        // when using -- this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName()
        // it will throw Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

        // return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
    }, this)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

---

With all that being said, I have the following **questions**:

- Why is `this` referring to the `window` rather than the object itself?
- How can I scope it to the object - ***WITHOUT*** treating `viewModel` as a function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

***I know this can be done by treating `viewModel` as a function, however, I was wondering if it is possible to use an object?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your singleton cake and eat it.

```
var viewModel = new function() {
    // Note that the anonymous function is instantiated via new,
    // effectively returning a singleton.
    this.firstName = ko.observable('John');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Doe');
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
    }, this);
}();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Great answer! I also added additional content but exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Dom the IIFE will keep any variables like `var foo = ...` from polluting the global namespace but it does not change `this`. So the edit you proposed actually modifies `window` via the `this` keyword. I'm glad my answer is helpful but I'm going to remove your edit.

Comment: Not a problem, but it seems to work in the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/6s8WC/3/ . Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It does work but check out this version of the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4B8Vx/. Also, this article might pique your interest, particularly sections 4 and 5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg578608.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

could do it like this too ( demo : http://jsfiddle.net/QLwj2/ )

```
var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.firstName = ko.observable('John');
    viewModel.lastName = ko.observable('Doe');
    viewModel.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return viewModel.firstName() + ' ' + viewModel.lastName();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I know this can be done by treating viewModel as a function, however, I want to make this particular viewModel a singleton so I feel an object would be more appropriate. Can ko.computed be used within an object?

Comment: Hi @Dom, yes - updated the post. Basically, instead of referring `this` which you do not have without the function, you need a way to get the first() and last() values from within the context of the ko.computed

Comment: I like your second answer but I'd never use first technique. EDIT: In fact I suggest you remove the first technique for fear someone will copy it, thinking it's a good idea.

Comment: @JeremyCook,  I wouldn't say I'm a knockout expert by a long shot, so would love to hear why. Is it the `ko.applyBindings()` bit, rather than new `viewModel()` ?

Comment: Check out this version of your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Zu3hA/1/) where I demonstrate that `this` is `window`. An alert pops up that says true, meaning you are modifying the `window` object.

Comment: ofcourse! the correct edit would be `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());` or some variant. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but @ryudice has already provided that answer. I think your second answer is perfectly valid. Remove your first answer and I'll gladly vote for the second.

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesnt mean your viewmodel because you are not inside a scope, since you are not inside a function, you are using object notation instead of a function. If you change your code to this:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.firstName= ko.observable('John');
    this.lastName= ko.observable('Doe');
    this.fullName= ko.computed(function(){
        // this = window
        // when using -- this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName()
        // it will throw Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

        // return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
    }, this);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
```

then it should work because you are creating a scope, and therefore `this` refers to the current scope.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I know this can be done by treating `viewModel` as a function, however, I want to make this particular `viewModel` a singleton so I feel an object would be more appropriate.  Can ko.computed be used within an object?

Answer (score 1):

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    },self);
}
```

To avoid confusion between this keywords, using self is a better approach. Because self is captured in the function’s closure, it remains available and consistent in any nested functions, such as the ko.computed evaluator. This convention is even more useful when it comes to event handlers, as you’ll see in many of the live examples.

I took this from the [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)  documentation itself.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not answer my question regarding ko.computed within objects.